# Test results getting ignored and fail

Tags: java, selenium, unit-testing, automated-tests, testng

While doing testing i got error as one of test ignored and second failed. have posted both classes of test class and driver manger  and also error showing after executing test.

This is my test class:

```
@BeforeSuite
public void setUp(){
    driver = DriverManager.getWebDriver();
    driver.get(Configuration.getInstance().getProperty("appUrl"));
}
@Test
public void testrequestDemo(){
    topNavigation = new TopNavigation(driver);
    page = topNavigation.clickRequestDemoLink();
    page.KeyInEmail("Azhar@gmail.com")
            .and().KeyinCompany("ABC");
}
```

DriverManager Class :

```
public class DriverManager {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private static DriverManager manager;

    private DriverManager(){
        init();
        driver = createDriver();
    }

    private void init(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                Configuration.getInstance().getProperty("chrome.executable"));


    }

    /**
     * This method will create webdriver instance based on the
     * property provided.
     * @return
     */

    private WebDriver createDriver(){
        if(Configuration.getInstance().getProperty("browser").equals(Constants.CHROME)){
            return new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(Configuration.getInstance().getProperty("browser").equals(Constants.FIREFOX)){
            return new FirefoxDriver();
        }else {
            return new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }

    private WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
    public static WebDriver getWebDriver(){
        if(manager==null){
            manager = new DriverManager();
            return manager.getDriver();
        }
        return manager.getDriver();
    }
}
```

This is error I am getting

> 1. For setUP test fail
> 2. For testrequestDemo test ignored>
>           co.pragra.testingframework.drivermanager.DriverManager.createDriver(DriverManager.java:99)
>       co.pragra.testingframework.drivermanager.DriverManager.(DriverManager.java:73)
>           co.pragra.testingframework.drivermanager.DriverManager.getWebDriver(DriverManager.java:113)
>           co.pragra.testingframework.testcases.HomePageTest.setUp(HomePageTest.java:37)

Comment: Please add actual error message with stacktrace and format question's code. Bad code format is very annoying.

Comment: onInit(), you're defining the Chrome driver, but createDriver() allows for a FireFox driver. Been some time since I used Selenium, but aren't those incompatible?

Comment: This is error I am getting : co.pragra.testingframework.drivermanager.DriverManager.createDriver(DriverManager.java:99) co.pragra.testingframework.drivermanager.DriverManager.(DriverManager.java:73) co.pragra.testingframework.drivermanager.DriverManager.getWebDriver(DriverManager.java:113) co.pragra.testingframework.testcases.HomePageTest.setUp(HomePageTest.java:37)